# How to calculate the "names" of Excel/LO Calc columns in Lua

Tags: excel, lua, libreoffice-calc

I need 1 to become 'A', 26 to become 'Z', 27 to become 'AA' so on until (in this case) 81  becoming 'CC'

from 'A' to 'Z' I can do something like

```lua
string.char(64 + i)
```

But can't figure out how to do this for the larger columns.

Comment: I don't know how you use it in LUA, but in spreadsheet formulas it's done like [=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1; i ;4);"1";"")](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?p=238272#p238272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```lua
function num2column(n)
  assert(type(n) == "number")

  local i = n
  local j = 0
  local ret = ""

  while true do
    j = i % 26
    i = i // 26 -- use i = math.floor(i / 26) if using Lua older than 5.3

    if j == 0 then
      j = 26
      i = i - 1
    end

    -- prepend the letter to ret
    ret = string.char(64 + j) .. ret

    if i == 0 then break end
  end
  return ret
end

print(num2column(27)) -- 'AA'
print(num2column(80)) -- 'CB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can translate this code from Basic to Lua:

```
Function ColumnNumberToString(ByVal the_column As Long) As String
  Dim s$
  Do while the_column >= 0
    s$ = Chr(65 +  the_column MOD 26) + s$
    the_column =  the_column \ 26 - 1
  Loop 
  ColumnNumberToString = s$
End Function
```

*This is from **Listing 6.16: Cell address in a readable form** from a book [**Useful Macro Information For OpenOffice.org By Andrew Pitonyak**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt)*